# Why is canlib behaving so slow?

Tags: python, c#, can-bus

This might be a shot in the dark, but this behavior has me stumped.

I'm writing a control gui for an embedded motor controller, communicating to a PC over CAN (using a kvaser light leaf 2). The bus is 1M bit/s and utilizing about 29% of the bus according to Kvaser Can King. The issue is that when I send a request to the embedded device for a specific piece of data, there is a long delay about 10 to 15 seconds, before it is displayed on my gui. The delay starts small, if I request the data right on start up its only about 1 second. If I let it sit for a few minutes

The first gui I wrote was in python using tkinter. I found that performance was marginal: meaning there was a small amount of processing of the CAN messages I could do before I would start to get the delay issue. I figured it was because of python being an interpreted language, maybe it is just too slow to keep up. So I wrote a new gui in C# since it is a compiled language and should run faster. But I get the same issue. Tried it with different host machines, different embedded dev boards and different kvasers, same problem.

Anyone know what might be going on?

so my python thread method looks like this:

```py
def can_thread():  
    global finished  
    global can_log_name  
    global temp_log_name  
    global yoko_log_name  
    global time_last  
    global logging  
    global start_time  
    global TU1_active  
    global TU2_active  
    global TV1_active  
    global TV2_active  
    global TW1_active  
    global TW2_active  
    global Tcool_active  
    global state_dic  
    global printlog  
    global yoko_cmd  
    global can_timeout  
    global missed_messages  
    finished = None  
    start_time = time()  
    time_last_1Hz = time()  
    time_last_4Hz = time()  
    while not finished:  
        time_now = time()  
        elapsed_time_1Hz = time_now - time_last_1Hz  
        elapsed_time_4Hz = time_now - time_last_4Hz  
        finished = get_can_message()  
        if elapsed_time_1Hz > 1:  
            if logging == True:  
                if not temp_log_name == None:  
                    tempText = str(text_time)+ "," + \  
                               TU1_temp["text"] + "," + \  
                               TU2_temp["text"] + "," + \  
                               TV1_temp["text"] + "," + \  
                               TV2_temp["text"] + "," + \  
                               TW1_temp["text"] + "," + \  
                               TW2_temp["text"] + "," + \  
                               ULPF_current["text"] + "," + \  
                               VLPF_current["text"] + "," + \  
                               WLPF_current["text"] + "," + \  
                               Tcool_temp["text"]  
                    f = open(temp_log_name, "a")  
                    f.write(tempText + "\n")  
                    f.close  
                if not yoko_log_name == None:  
                    f = open(yoko_log_name, "a")  
                    f.write(str(text_time)+ "," + yoko_cmd)  
                    f.close  
            time_last_1Hz = time_now  
        if elapsed_time_4Hz > 0.25:  
            while incoming_message_queue.qsize() > 0:  
                frame = incoming_message_queue.get()  
                if frame.id == broadcast_frame_id + get_id():  
                    broadcast_frame(frame)  
                    None  
                elif frame.id == UTA2_frame_id + get_id():  
                    UTA2_frame(frame)  
                    None  
                elif frame.id == volt_cur_pow_frame_id + get_id():  
                    volt_curr_pwr_frame(frame)  
                    None  
                elif frame.id == state_faults_frame_id + get_id():  
                    state_faults_frame(frame)  
                    None  
                else:  
                    None  
            if missed_messages > 2:  
                can_inidicator_lbl["bg"] = "red"  
                can_inidicator_lbl["text"] = "CAN Timeout"  
            else:  
                can_inidicator_lbl["bg"] = "green"  
                can_inidicator_lbl["text"] = "CAN Traffic detected"  
            elapsed_time_4Hz = time_now  
        while outgoing_message_queue.qsize() > 0:  
            msg = outgoing_message_queue.get()  
            cn.ch.write(msg)
```

My C# Thread method looks like this:

```
private void CanThread()
        {
            while(m_OkToRunThread)
            {
                try
                {
                    var result = m_CanMessage.ReadCanBusWithWait(m_canHandle, CAN_TIMEOUT);
                    if(result == Canlib.canStatus.canOK)
                    {
                        m_canTimeoutCount = 0;
                        m_canTimedOut = false;
                        CanMessageEventArgs e = new CanMessageEventArgs();
                        e.Message = m_CanMessage;
                        e.CanTimeOut = m_canTimedOut;
                        OnMessageReceived(e);
                    }
                    else if(result == Canlib.canStatus.canERR_NOMSG)
                    {
                        m_canTimeoutCount++;
                        if(m_canTimeoutCount > ALLOWED_TIMED_OUT_MESSAGES)
                        {
                            m_canTimedOut = true;
                            CanMessageEventArgs e = new CanMessageEventArgs();
                            e.Message = m_CanMessage;
                            e.CanTimeOut = m_canTimedOut;
                            OnMessageReceived(e);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        m_OkToRunThread = false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    //m_OkToRunThread = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please create a *minimal* example that demonstrates the problem!

Comment: First post edited to show thread methods

Comment: How do you know your CAN bus is set for 1Mbps?  Have you put a scope on it?  That would be quite revealing.  You should be able to see if there are long delays between sequences, or if it really is the bitstream that's slowing down.

Comment: Are you getting errors?  CAN isn't high-performance to begin with, but it can survive a low-quality connection with retries.

Comment: A 10-15 seconds delay is unlikely to have anything to do with the CAN bus. I'd rather suspect some deadlock or starvation in your thread implementation.

Comment: It looks like I need to clarify a bit more: I don't think the CAN bus itself is slowed down. I can put a break point in the embedded code for transmit of the reply and see that it hits as soon as the request is sent. The message is getting into the kvaser hardware, but something is happening between when the message is received and when my test program processes it. Either in the driver or in my code. I was hoping someone else had encountered this problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

So like many times in software, I have found the guy who has caused all the problems with my code, and he is me.

To notify the user that the embedded processor is still working/not frozen, I was printing the raw CAN message on the GUI every time it comes in.

I switched to a "CAN detected/ CAN timeout" indication in C# and all my lagging problems went away. The ToString method for the CAN message isn't trivial and calling that every time a message comes in at 29% load of a 1Mb/s bus is a lot of processing. It was lagging JUST behind the bus and the delay was from buffering.

Note that this solution doesn't work in python. The interpreted nature of python can't keep up at these speeds. Having tried the solution in python first and not succeeding is why it took me so long to find it in C#.